# Comparison b/w Lazy loading with double check lock Vs Class level initialization

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

Assuming I have an **empty constructor** for a single ton class , which of the below 2 approaches is better to return an instance from a public getInstance method?

1. Class level initialization
       {

   ```
   public class ClassName{

   private static ClassName instance = new ClassName ();
   }
   ```

   }
2. Lazy loading with double check lock

   ```
   if (null == instance) {

           synchronized (this) {
       if(null == instance) {
           instance = new className();
               }
       }
   }
   ```

I was thinking Class level initialization wouldn't create any harm here. But would like to confirm it from the experts. Please help

Comment: Any reason not to use an enum with a single value instead? That's even simpler. I'd avoid double-checked locking if you can. (I'd also avoid "yoda conditions" of `if (null == instance)` as `if (instance == null)` is more readable to most people. Oh, and you can't synchronize on `this` within a static method - and the method *would* have to be static...

Comment: `synchronize(this)` -> `synchronized(SingletonClass.class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a private constructor and a `final` instance field.  Ideally the class should be `final` as well.  The simplest way to do all this is to use an enum

```
public enum Singleton implements MyInterface {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the enum way very good for single guys, it's good for stateless singleton, and stateless singleton would make all methods static rather follow singleton approach.

Comment: @user2511414 all singletons should be statelsss, if possible, but you don't again much by not using an `enum`. So while it's not good, it is no worse.

Comment: Not agree, so if all singleton should be stateless, the `Math` class should be singleton too, or `ContextInitialize`, or `System`!

Comment: @user2511414 Good point.  You only need a singleton if you need to implement an interface, which ideally should be stateless.

Comment: Good point, but usually for making an implement of an interface as single, I rather to give some hand of a naming and directory module and let him just take care about the instances and management, your example would like `ObjectFactory` in JEE